# Error detected in pubspec File That says No file or variants found

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This is My Pubspec.yaml File

```
name: pet_flutterapp
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: "none"
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.19.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.2
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - lib/asset/imgs
    - lib/asset/svgs
```

I tryed to Attach assets But i got This error

[This is that Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liq7m.png)

*Please Tell me Where I made Mistake*

Answer (score 0):

```
 flutter:
   uses-material-design: true
   assets:
     - lib/asset/imgs/ <-----add this
     - lib/asset/svgs/
```

Comment: Thank you,

this Small "/" this make this error.

Comment: @AjSaleh - please accept the answer by clicking the tick on the left. This will tell the community that you're happy that your question has a solution.